# How to split string into parts defined by brackets

Tags: java, regex

It seems really simple, but I can't find a solution. I need to get values from a string like `{value1}{value2}.....{valueN}`.
I've tried to create pattern as: `(\\{(.*)\\})*` or `(\\{(.*?)\\})*`. But in both cases I get only one value: everything between marginal brackets or the last value. I would need to replace the `(.*)` with something with meaning `anything except }{`.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for:

```
String str = "{value1}{value2}...{valueN}";
str = str.subString(1,str.length-2); // to crop the first and last bracket
String[] results = str.split("\\}\\{"); // to get an array of results
```

I don't like matching stuff with regex when you can go for something less confusing. Especially for the next dev who's gonna work on the same code.

Comment: It was my idea also, but I don't like this solution; it is not "pure" ;-)

Comment: @agad: it can't get more pure than this, if the format is defined as you describe in your question and comments (values also containing arbitrary unescaped curly brackets where **only** the `}{` pair is the delimiter).

Comment: From experience it is easier to understand multiple lines of splits rather then complex regex. But it's up to everyone to choose their way. You can't make mistake choosing any of the solutions.

Comment: @Lenymm: Not to mention that the described format might not even be part of a regular grammar. I didn't check, just food for thought.

Comment: 'code' how can we get if String is like this                        <#if ("{or_license_no}"=='999999')> #({' '})# <#else> #({or_name1})# </#if>

Answer (score 1):

Try this string pattern:

```
"\\{([^}]+)\\}"
```

Comment: @all Please try your answer before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ungreedy operator (`?`) so that the `.+` captures as little as possible...

```
{.+?}
```

Comment: As I wrote above: greedy as well as ungreedy quantify results in one group only. The difference is in the group value. I would need to get N groups.

Answer (score 0):

You should use more specific matching criteria, like maybe a not right curly brace rather than a match all...

```
{[^}]+}
```

Comment: But the value can contain curly bracket. Only }{ pair is not allowed. More over it still returns just last value, not all N (see my comment above).